# Hive on Tez: Could not find or load main class 400

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I'm trying to configuring the **Hive on Tez** by following the [formal document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Tez) and the [Tez installation guide](http://tez.apache.org/install.html). By overview my environment and configuration are as the following: -

1. Apache Hadoop/YARN version `3.1.2`
2. Apache Hive version `3.1.2`
3. Apache Tez version `0.9.2`
4. openjdk version `1.8.0_242`
5. OS: CentOS version `7.7.1908` and Debian version `10 (buster)`

So far, I've achieved to start the `YARN/Spark/Hive` and `Hive(mr)` with `bin/hive` and `bin/beeline` properly. Then I move to the next step for configuring the `Hive on Tez` as the following information: -

#### Environment variable

```bash
export TEZ_CONF_DIR=/opt/tez/conf
export TEZ_JARS=/opt/tez/*:/opt/tez/lib/*
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$TEZ_CONF_DIR:$TEZ_JARS:$(hadoop classpath)
```

#### HDFS

```bash
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /apps/tez \
&& hdfs dfs -put /opt/tez/* /apps/tez \
&& hdfs dfs -chmod g+w /apps/tez
```

#### tez-site.xml

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
        <value>${fs.defaultFS}/apps/tez/,${fs.defaultFS}/apps/tez/lib/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>tez.use.cluster.hadoop-libs</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### hive-site.xml

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
        <value>tez</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:postgresql://metastore-db:5432/metastore</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>some-user</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>some-password</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

#### Start the Hive Server 2

```bash
${HIVE_HOME}/bin/hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.enable.doAs=false
```

There is an application displayed at `Resource Manager UI` and its status is `FAILED`, together with the `hiveserver2` show me the error as the following:-

```bash
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-03-10 08:28:06.410]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1583471849377_0012_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2020-03-10 08:28:06.413]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 400


[2020-03-10 08:28:06.414]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class 400


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: 
http://node-master:61688/cluster/app/application_1583471849377_0012 
Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

I also have a chance to visit the application log on YARN

The `stderr` mentions as `Error: Could not find or load main class 400`

The `launch_container.sh` mentions as

```bash
echo "Launching container"
exec /bin/bash -c "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java  \
-Xmx1228m \
-Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp \
-server \
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
-Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  \

400 \ # <---- Suspected which may be related to the above error.

-Dlog4j.configuratorClass=org.apache.tez.common.TezLog4jConfigurator \
-Dlog4j.configuration=tez-container-log4j.properties \
-Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1583471849377_0012/container_1583471849377_0012_02_000001 \
-Dtez.root.logger=INFO,CLA \
-Dsun.nio.ch.bugLevel='' \
org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster \
--session \
1>/opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1583471849377_0012/container_1583471849377_0012_02_000001/stdout \
2>/opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1583471849377_0012/container_1583471849377_0012_02_000001/stderr "
```

I've no idea where the error `Could not find or load main class 400` is from and the only one may be related is inside the `launch_container.sh` as mention above.

Could you please help to advise how to solve this trouble? Am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

The gist for displaying the long lines is

https://gist.github.com/charleech/8cd615c0236626882c7a3ea7532ad4d5

Comment: Can you show a copy of that shell script or whatever evaluates the Java command?

Comment: I've seen the `launch_container.sh` via the `resource manager UI` when drill down to the applications log by clicking the `application id`. Please correct me If I'm wrong. I understand that the `Tez` is the one who creates the `launch_container.sh`. At that page there are several files, e.g. `directory.info`, `launch_container.sh`, `stderr`, `stdout` and so on. Do you want to see the whole content of the `launch_container.sh`?

Comment: I think so, yes. If that's the file that templates out the Java command

Comment: Since it is too long to post here. I create a gist at https://gist.github.com/charleech/8cd615c0236626882c7a3ea7532ad4d5 Please note that I wrap it by adding new line and back slash for increasing the readable.

Comment: Hmm. There's a separate file that contains a template like `exec /bin/bash -c "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xmx{{ tez_heap }}`. I'm not sure what it's called, though

Comment: Could you please help to guide where can I find that file? inside the `YARN UI`? or at the host machine which the `Tez `is installed? So far the `/opt/tez` and `/opt/tez/lib` only contain the jar files. The `/opt/tez/conf` contains 2 template files `tez-default-template.xml` and `tez-runtime-default-template.xml`. I've no any clue about that template for Java command.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know where it is. Something obviously creates that launch container file

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll try to dig deeper to `Tez` Git repository and hope that there may be some clue.

Comment: To be honest, I've only ever installed Tez as part of HDP with Ambari, never manually. If you just want a different Hive execution layer, you could try Spark or MR3 https://mr3.postech.ac.kr/ or install Presto instead

Comment: Yes, I would like to find some alternative for comparing and evaluating. Thank you so much for pointing me to the good resource.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the 400 class came from a configuration parameter on file $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml and it indeed showed up on the launch_container.sh.
I edited the following property in the file.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <!-- <value>400</value> -->
    <value>-Xmx256m</value>
</property>
```

You can find further information of this parameter on [this cloudera doc](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html).